# How to move from a QTableWidget to the next widget using the tab-key

Tags: python, keyboard, pyqt5, qtablewidget, tab-ordering

I want to know how to move from a table-widget to the next widget when I press the tab key in PyQt.

The current widget sequence is composed of line-edit > combo-box > table-widget > push-button. In the line-edit, when you press the tab key in the beginning, the combo-box > table widget is moved to in sequence. However, in the table-widget, repeatedly moving to the end, it moves to the `0,0` row and column of the table-widget again, not to the next widget (the push-button).

How do I fix this?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (i.e. click on the tick symbol). If it didn't, please explain what else is needed.

Answer (score 7):

There are two main ways to fix this.

The first, and simplest, way is to use [setTabKeyNavigation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#tabKeyNavigation-prop) to completely disable moving between cells using the tab-key. The arrow keys must then be used to navigate between cells in the table.

The second way is to modify the keypress event handing for the table, so that <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the last cell and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in the first cell moves the focus to the next/previous widget.

The demo script below demonstrates both these approaches:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 3)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Disable Table Tabbing', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.table.installEventFilter(self)
        self.edit.setFocus()

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.table.tabKeyNavigation():
            self.button.setText('Enable Table Tabbing')
            self.table.setTabKeyNavigation(False)
        else:
            self.button.setText('Disable Table Tabbing')
            self.table.setTabKeyNavigation(True)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
            source is self.table and source.isEnabled() and
            source.tabKeyNavigation()):
            index = self.table.currentIndex()
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backtab:
                if index.row() == index.column() == 0:
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.focusNextPrevChild(
                        self.table, False)
                    return True
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
                model = self.table.model()
                if (index.row() == model.rowCount() - 1 and
                    index.column() == model.columnCount() - 1):
                    QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.focusNextPrevChild(
                        self.table, True)
                    return True
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 250)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I go with the simplest way. Thank you!